# How to open newsboat feed in browser

Tags: firefox, 20.04, software-center, rss

After opening a feed in newsboat, we have the option to open in browser using the `o` key.

However, when I press the o key, I get `Browser returned error code 127`.

Looking online, I'm told to add `browser firefox` to the config file of newsboat. Somewhere else I'm told to add `browser "w3m %u"`. I've tried both and neither worked and I still get the error above.

What can I do to make `o` work in newsboat?

My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ which newsboat
/snap/bin/newsboat
```

`$ echo $BROWSER` returns nothing

```
$ newsboat -v
newsboat r2.20.1-3-gb8c2a-dirty - https://newsboat.org/
Copyright (C) 2006-2015 Andreas Krennmair
Copyright (C) 2015-2020 Alexander Batischev
Copyright (C) 2006-2017 Newsbeuter contributors
Copyright (C) 2017-2020 Newsboat contributors 
Newsboat is free software licensed under the MIT License. 
(Type `/snap/newsboat/2764/usr/local/bin/newsboat -vv' to see the full text.)
It bundles:
  - JSON for Modern C++ library, licensed under the MIT License: https://github.com/nlohmann/json
  - optional-lite library, licensed under the Boost Software License: https://github.com/martinmoene/optional-lite
  - expected-lite library, licensed under the Boost Software License: https://github.com/martinmoene/expected-lite 
newsboat r2.20.1-3-gb8c2a-dirty
System: Linux 5.4.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Compiler: g++ 7.5.0
ncurses: ncurses 6.1.20180127 (compiled with 6.1)
libcurl: libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3 (compiled with 7.58.0)
SQLite: 3.22.0 (compiled with 3.22.0) libxml2: compiled with 2.9.4
```

---

```
$ cat ~/.newsboat/config
cat: /home/user/.newsboat/config: No such file or directory
```

The last output is because I make my changes in the directory `~/snap/newsboat/2764/.newsboat/config`, which works for me when I put in other config lines like `auto refresh` and `refresh timer`. So maybe that's not an issue?

Comment: Please add output of `which newsboat`, `echo $BROWSER`, `newsboat -v`, `cat ~/.newsboat/config` to the question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1256425/edit) it.

Comment: @N0rbert I have added the outputs of those commands to my above question.

Comment: For more reproducible results I would suggest to remove snapped version and install deb-package instead with `snap remove newsboat` , `sudo apt-get install newsboat` . Then copy *config* and *urls* files to *~/.newsboat* .

Answer (score 3):

You have to add one configuration option to `~/.newsboat/config` config file:

```
browser "firefox %u"
```

---

See `man newsboat` for details locally or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/newsboat.1.html).

Comment: I added that to the top line of my config file and still it does not work. The other commands I have in the config file, like refresh everry 1 minute, does work. So Im pretty sure im editing the correct file and it's being read.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a more elegant answer out there, but because I didn't want to spend too much time in the weeds on this, one option that worked for me was adding:

```
"browser "open -a safari '%u'"
```

..in the config file. All credit to this Reddit (https://www.reddit.com/r/newsboat/comments/ijm8yw/im_lost_with_browsers/) that provided ideas, and some explanations.

On Linux (PopOS installation), added the following:

```
"browser "xdg-open '%u'"
```

Comment: How do you run Safari on Ubuntu?

Comment: :) I don't. I was installing this on MacOS. But incidentally, also installed this on PopOS and was syncing the cache.db and urls through Github. I've updated the answer for the Linux config file I have. Thanks,

Comment: Neither MacOS, nor PopOs are on-topic here.

Comment: Was just responding to the original question and passing on what might be helpful. If this shouldn't be on this forum, fair. Mentioned PopOS because it's an Ubuntu variant.

Answer (score 1):

Not really adding much, but adding this to the `~/.newboat/config` worked for me:

```
browser "$BROWSER %u"
```

Obviously I have my browser (currently firefox) set as the BROWSER env variable in `~/.profile`.